# Can I optimize html files with r.js?

Tags: javascript, html, optimization, requirejs, r.js

Actually the subject expresses what I need.
I've tried like this:

```
node ../../r.js -o app.build.js
```

I tried to include html files as modules:

```
...
modules: [
...
    {
        name: "app/views/site/index.html"
    }
...
],
```

but uglify optimizer did not processed the file.

If somebody knows how, I'd appreciate your advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r.js` does not optimize HTML files.

Comment: Can you advice something that do that?

Comment: Sorry. I don't know of a solution for this. I've never been in a situation where I felt the need to minify HTML files.